# Should I use a common prefix for my custom widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and I had a quick look at the [style guide](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Style-guide-for-Flutter-repo) but I didn't find anything about a 'common prefix' for a custom widget.
I come from angular where all the components of a package have a common prefix, so it's easier to choose between a library component and the personalized version (e.g. 'dx-button' and 'app-dx-button' where 'app' is my common prefix). This is because Angular uses a prefix that is defined in the file config of the app and is automatically added to the creation of the new component.
Is there something similar for Flutter?
Should I follow this 'prefix' patter?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is something similar in Flutter. My custom widgets are manually tagged like this: `PROJECTINITIALS_NAMEOFTHECOMPONENT`.

For example, my `ExtendedFab` is called `QFExtendedFab` and has all the kinds of features that I reuse throughout the app.